# Golang missing checkbox in commit tab along with Commit message area

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

[image: Unable to pick the file i need to commit]

[image: Already checked Use non-modal commit interface]

I have Intellij CE, there the commit tab is working as expected.
My hunch is I disabled some setting/config, but not sure what or how to solve it.

Anyone faced anything similar before, kindly help.

Comment: Does the issue occur with the light IDE theme as well? I'd report it at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and attach the logs via Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data.

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes, its independent of the theme i choose.
I updated the goland version to latest one; Uninstalled and installed again.
(hoping it would solve the issue) Nothing worked.

Comment: See if File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings...: https://i.imgur.com/kbrkC7w.png helps. If not, file a bug in YouTrack with the logs so that we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the issue was, but resetting the settings via File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings... helped.

[image: Restore Default Settings]